# Bing Map Pushpin with Custom Image and variable text

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps, pushpin

I need to add on a BingMap control one or more pushpins with custom static image and text, which is set in code. Here is my pushpin template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="PushpinTemplate" TargetType="maps:Pushpin">
    <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid"
                Width="39"
                Height="48">
                <Image Source="Images/pin.png" Stretch="None"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Text" />
     </Grid>
 </ControlTemplate>
```

How to make property TextBlock.Text can be changed programmatically? Say bind it to a property Pushpin.Content.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by dynamic generation of control template.

```
    private ControlTemplate CreateTemplate(string image, string text)
    {
        string xaml = "<ControlTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\" xmlns:maps=\"clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps\" TargetType=\"maps:Pushpin\"><Grid x:Name=\"ContentGrid\" Width=\"39\" Height=\"48\"><Image Source=\"" + image + "\" Stretch=\"None\"/><TextBlock Margin=\"14,2,0,0\" FontSize=\"20\" Text=\"" + text + "\" /></Grid></ControlTemplate>";
        ControlTemplate сt = (ControlTemplate)XamlReader.Load(xaml);
        return сt;
    }
```